# Взять несколько данных из одного ввода

Tags: c++

Добрый день, подскажите, вот ввел я строку в c++:

```
string a;
cin>>a;
```

Я ввел:

```
1 2 3 4 5...n
```

Как из этого вывода получить интовые числа `a1, a2, a3, a4, ..., an,` если не известно n(количество чисел через пробел)

Comment: Что Вы ввели? И что получили в `a`? (Ответ: в `a` -- "1")

Comment: Может так:

    #include <iostream>
    #include <sstream>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
      string a;
      getline(cin, a);
      istringstream iss(a);
      while(!iss.eof()) {
        int a1;
        iss >> a1;
        cout << a1 << endl;
      }
      return 0;
    }

Comment: Или можно вызвать 

    FILE *fmemopen(void *buf, size_t size, const char *mode);

и использовать `fscanf()`.

Но это все некрасиво (лишняя память под буфер для FILE в libio). 

Я предпочитаю цикл с вызовом `strtol()`.

Comment: @avp: числа могут быть из больше, чем одной цифры, надо честно сканировать.

@alexlz: можно даже проще:

    int a1;
    while (iss >> a1)
        cout << a1 << endl;

Comment: @VladD, 

     числа могут быть из больше, чем одной цифры, надо честно сканировать

Если "биться" за каждый байт, то по идее - да. Выбрали очередное число - увеличили массив. Но, тут возникает другой вопрос с realloc-ом. 

Когда массив растет, то не факт, что его можно увеличить "по месту". В таком случае возникает фрагментация памяти. Причем очевидно, что такие фрагменты (только  что освобожденная память) не могут быть использованы (в нашем цикле) для последующего расширения массива.


Вот как эти "свободные" фрагменты оценивать - как свободную или на самом деле занятую память?

Comment: А почему никто не предлагает использовать вектор (`std::vector`), а городят с realloc?

Comment: @alexlz: почему бы вам не опубликовать ваш код как ответ? Я бы опубликовал свой, но он основан на вашем.

Comment: @avp: Вы имеете в виду сначала выделить память по максимуму, а затем отдать излишек? Если мы любой ценой хотим избежать realloc'а, надо делать в два прохода: сначала просканировать строку и выяснить точное к-во чисел, затем выделить память и прочитать их.

---
Я бы, собственно, и правда завёл `std::vector` и сказал ему `reserve` с ожидаемым количеством чисел.

---
Кстати, ожидаемое количество чисел -- `(len+1)/2`. (К примеру, для односимвольной строки будет 1.)

Comment: @KoVadim, Вы же понимаете, что vector просто маскирует realloc (либо его аналог, если задан свой аллокатор).

IMHO всегда лучше разъяснить суть дела, а лингвистическая обертка вторична.

Comment: @VladD опубликуйте. Одним нажатием мыши тут не обойтись, а причёсывать -- лениво.

Comment: @avp  я конечно понимаю. Но может все таки лучше сразу объяснить по простому, а потом объяснять по сложному? Вектор умеет достаточно хорошо перевыделять память.

Comment: @KoVadim, можно и с вектором (для любителей крестов).

@VladD, с `(len+1)/2` согласен (даже, говоря о `len/2` из `gnu`  `getline()`, надо учесть, что последняя строка файла может быть из одной цифры и не заканчиваться `\n`).

Если серьезно экономить память, то очевидно - 2 прохода. На практике же, я бы делал `malloc`, а в конце `realloc`, если можно высвободить больше `LIM` байт. Если длина неизвестна, то `realloc` с неким инкрементом.

Величина `LIM` зависит от задачи. Думаю, если можно освободить меньше 32 байт (не спрашивайте почему, чисто интуитивно), то в любом случае `realloc` не нужен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы сделал как-то так (код основан на идее [[@alexlz](/users/352/alexlz)](/users/352/alexlz)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string inputline;
    getline(cin, inputline);
    istringstream iss(inputline);

    vector<int> values;
    values.reserve((inputline.length() + 1)/2); // heuristics
    int inputValue;
    while (iss >> inputValue)
        values.push_back(inputValue);

    // это модный синтаксис C++11, поменяйте, если у вас не компилируется
    for (auto v : values)
        cout << v << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Это, конечно, не самый быстрый вариант, зато на мой взгляд самый простой с точки зрения C++.

---

Ещё более короткий и концептуальный (хотя и менее понятный, как на мой вкус) вариант таков:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string inputline;
    getline(cin, inputline);

    istringstream iss(inputline);
    vector<int> values((istream_iterator<int>(iss)),
                       istream_iterator<int>());

    // синтаксис C++11, поменяйте, если у вас не компилируется
    for (auto v : values)
        cout << v << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Кто первым догадается, для чего дополнительные скобки вокруг первого аргумента в конструкторе `vector<int>`? (Чур, компилятор не спрашивать.)

Comment: @VladD, я конечно понимаю, что все стремятся к новому и прогрессивному, но 

    g++.real (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

не компилирует. Вопрос безусловно к изготовителям updates для Ubuntu.

А Вы знаете, что у многих людей (в серьезных организациях) рабочей системой является вообще RHEL 5.3?

А так, конечно, красиво.

Comment: @avp: а на что ругается? Если на новый синтаксис `for`, то это поэлементный вывод массива, то есть просто

    for (auto it = values.begin(); it != values.end(); ++it)
        cout << *it << endl;

У меня нет под рукой Ubuntu, проверить не на чем.

Comment: все компилирует и нечиво валить на убунту (хотя она ещё тот фрукт). Добавьте в параметры компилятора `-std=c++0x` и все будет ок.

А c rhel - это уже другое дело.

Но @VladD должен был бы подписать, что он новым стандартом пишет.

Comment: Добавил ещё один вариант.

Comment: @KoVadim, Вы правы, с `-std=c++0x` все ок (первый вариант).

@VladD, на `auto v` ругалась. Все остальное наведенное.

А вот второй вариант уже и с `-std=c++0x` не собирается.

    g++ -std=c++0x tarr.c
    ...
     error: ‘istream_iterator’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: @avp: может, надо `#include <iterator>`?

Comment: @VladD - второй вариант у меня не компилиться никаким компилятором, даже 4.8. istream_iterator я конечно добавил:)

Comment: @VladD, да, с `<iterator>` собралось (`g++ -std=c++0x ...`)

А Вы чем и где собираете?

Comment: @avp: VS 2012 компилирует, но ideone не скомпилировало. Однако, вот так получилось: http://ideone.com/68DYAD (дополнительная переменная для `istringstream`).

Comment: @avp: VS 2012 SP 1 на Windows 7. Интересно, в чём проблема с компиляцией? У меня в проблемном месте вызывается такая перегрузка:

    explicit basic_istringstream(const _Mystr& _Str,
        ios_base::openmode _Mode = ios_base::in)
        : _Mybase(&_Stringbuffer),
            _Stringbuffer(_Str, _Mode | ios_base::in)
        {    // construct readable character buffer from NTCS
        }

(а g++ 4.7.2 на ideone эту перегрузку не находит/не использует).

Comment: @VladD, как на ideone собралось (g++ -std=c++0x ...) и работает.

Насколько я вижу, второй вариант здесь и вариант на ideone различаются 

    istringstream(inputline)  // hashcode
      и
    istringstream(iss)        // ideone

Так в варианте с `istringstream(inputline)`

     error: no matching function for call to ‘std::istream_iterator<int>::istream_iterator(std::string&)’


и еще простыня сообщений.

Comment: @avp: Поставил свежий Cygwin и разобрался: в gcc конструктор `istream_iterator` с `istream` хочет lvalue, а у MSVC --- нет. Поправлю код для универсальности.

Answer (score 2):

Не удержался. Посмотрел на красоту С++ в ответе [@VladD](/users/10105/vladd) и решил сравнить производительность двух подходов.

Просто написал функцию (**strtolarr()**), которая для заданной `char[]` строки с числами, разделенными isspace символами, возвращает динамический массив чисел типа long, используя библиотечную функцию `strtol()`.

Результат:

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ g++ -std=c++0x -O3 speed.cpp strtolarr.o  -o speed 
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./speed 1000
speed string 100 numbers vector-iterator: 1000 loops 47 msec
 Sum=4950000
speed char[] 100 numbers strtolarr(): 1000 loops 16 msec
 Sum=4950000
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ ./speed
speed string 100 numbers vector-iterator: 1000000 loops 16120 msec
 Sum=4950000000
speed char[] 100 numbers strtolarr(): 1000000 loops 4997 msec
 Sum=4950000000
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$ grep CPU /proc/cpuinfo 
model name  : Pentium(R) Dual-Core  CPU      E5400  @ 2.70GHz
avp@avp-xub11:~/hashcode$
```

меня просто потясла цена, которую надо платить за красоту.

Код тестовой программы.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

#include <sys/time.h>

long long
mtime()
{
  struct timeval t;

  gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
  long long mt = (long long)t.tv_sec * 1000 + t.tv_usec / 1000;
  return mt;
}

// must be in "include"
struct lvec {
  long capacity, size;
  long data[1];
};

extern "C" struct lvec *strtolarr(const char *str, char **eptr);
// end of "include"

int main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char str[100000];
  int l = 0, l1 = 0, i, loops = av[1] ? atoi(av[1]) : 1000000;

  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++, l += l1)
    l1 = sprintf (str+l,"%d ",i);

  // C++ style (string + vector)
  string line(str);
  long long start = mtime(), sum;
  for (sum = i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
    istringstream iss(line);
    vector<long> v((istream_iterator<long>(iss)),
                       istream_iterator<long>());
    for (auto e : v)
      sum += e;
  }

  cout << "speed string 100 numbers vector-iterator: " 
       << i << " loops " << mtime()-start << " msec\n" 
       << " Sum=" << sum << '\n';

  // C style (char[] + dynamic array)
  start = mtime();
  for (sum = i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
    char *ep;
    struct lvec *v = strtolarr(str, &ep);
    for (int j = 0; j < v->size; j++)
      sum += v->data[j];
    free(v);
  }

  cout << "speed char[] 100 numbers strtolarr(): " 
       << i << " loops " << mtime()-start << " msec\n"
       << " Sum=" << sum << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Посмотрите внимательно, может я где-то в нем серьезно ошибся и поэтому 7 строк C++ работают в три раза дольше 7-ми строк в Си-стиле?

А это код **strtolarr**. Можно транслировать, как gcc, так и g++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct lvec {
  long capacity, size;
  long data[1];
};

#define INIVAL 14
#define DYNAINCR(s) ((s < (4*INIVAL)) ? (s)/2 + 1 : (s)/4 + 1)
#define DYNASIZE(c) (sizeof(struct lvec) + ((c) - 1)*sizeof(long))
#define DYNAOVLIM (32/sizeof(long))

struct lvec *
strtolarr (const char *str, char **eptr)
{
  struct lvec *res = (struct lvec *)malloc(DYNASIZE(INIVAL));

  if (res) {
    res->size = 0;
    res->capacity = INIVAL;
    long l;
    int  i;

    errno = 0;
    while (!errno) {
      l = strtol(str, eptr, 10);
      if (str == *eptr) {
        while (**eptr && isspace(**eptr))
          (*eptr)++;
        break; // OK
      }
      if (res->size == res->capacity) {
        //  printf ("cap %ld new cap %ld\n", \
                    res->capacity, res->capacity + DYNAINCR(res->capacity));
        res->capacity += DYNAINCR(res->capacity);
        struct lvec *t = (struct lvec *)realloc(res, DYNASIZE(res->capacity));
        if (!t) {
          free(res);
          res = t;
          break;
        }
        res = t;
      }
      res->data[res->size++] = l;
      str = *eptr;
    }
    if (res && res->capacity - res->size > DYNAOVLIM) {
      res->capacity = res->size ? res->size : 1;
      res = (struct lvec *)realloc(res, DYNASIZE(res->capacity));
      //      printf ("fin cap %ld\n", res->capacity);
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

Если есть вопросы, обязательно постараюсь ответить.

Comment: попрофилировать бы это, но с очень большой вероятностью скажу, что главным тормозом будет ввод через стрим (то есть эта строка `vector<long> v((istream_iterator<long>(iss)), istream_iterator<long>());`).

Comment: Не удивительно, `stringstream` известен тормозами.

Если предстоит вводить мегабайты текста, надо, конечно, писать кастомный десериализтор. С другой стороны, если текста и правда много, текстовый формат ввода — сам по себе уже ошибка.

Если же мы вводим и правда с клавиатуры, или одну-две строки из файла, наш выигрыш от более сложного алгоритма будет незаметен.

+1 за прекрасный анализ!

Comment: @avp: На самом деле, я удивлён, что работает _всего_ втрое быстрее.

Comment: Добавил для C++ 2 варианта разбора строки `strtol()` с возвратом `vector`.

    vector<long> strtolvec(const char *str, char **eptr);
    vector<long> strtolvec(const string str, int *endi);

Поскольку код очевиден, просто привожу результаты:

avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode/speed$ ./speed
    string 100 numbers vector-iterator: 1000000 loops 8034 msec
    char[] 100 numbers strtolarr(): 1000000 loops 2140 msec
    char[] 100 numbers strtolvec(): 1000000 loops 2536 msec
    string 100 numbers strtolvec(): 1000000 loops 2545 msec
    model name : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz

Answer (score 0):

```
//определим количество элементов

int n = (a.length()-1)/2;

int mas[n];
int c = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<a.length(); i+2) {
  mas[c]=a.at(i);
  c++;
}
```

Ну я бы сделал так

Comment: Эээ... а если введено аж одно число 12345678, чему будет равно ваше `n`?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arr[100], a = 0;
    string buf;
    char entering[255];

    cin.getline(entering, 255);

    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++){
        if (entering[i] != ' '){
          buf.push_back(entering[i]);
        }
        else {
            arr[a] = atoi(buf.c_str());
            a++;
            buf.clear();
        }
    }

    arr[a] = atoi(buf.c_str());
    a++;
    // вывод
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " " << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @perfect, а сами-то эту программу пробовали?

Даже если добавить 

    #include <stdlib.h>

а то 

    error: ‘atoi’ was not declared in this scope

вылезает, то все равно работает неправильно. 

И кстати, как Вы думаете обрабатывать ошибки ввода (например, буква вместо цифры)?

Comment: у меня она очень прекрасно работает (msvs 2010). atoi можно заменить на strtol. а насчет ввода букв так в вопросе сказано: Как из этого вывода получить интовые числа

насчет проверки так можно написать функцию которая сканирует ввод на наличие буквенных символов кроме пробела или можно этой функцией проверять уже порции полученных данных (т.е. переменную buf), я в примерочных кодах намеренно не ввожу проверки - главное осознать алгоритм а остальное можно добавить позднее

Comment: @perfect, это Вам так **кажется**.

Обратите внимание на 

    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++){
        if (entering[i] != ' '){
          buf.push_back(entering[i]);
        }
    ....

Задумайтесь, **что Вы на самом деле** обрабатываете.

Например у меня при вводе 

     1 2 3

в выводе было 5 чисел

    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ tarr.c
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
    1 2 3
    1 
    2 
    3 
    0 
    0 
    avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ 

Поответственней подходите к ответам.

Comment: чего то я не допонимаю

http://shot.qip.ru/00bCcA-1dD49eotF/

Comment: Вам **просто повезло**.

Дело в том, что содержимое 255-ти байт в `char entering[255];` **неизвестно какое**. 

Вы вводите начало этого массива, а обрабатываете **все** 255 байт.

Это серьезная ошибка.

Comment: а так )
http://shot.qip.ru/00bCcA-2dD49eotG/

Comment: @perfect, уже лучше (стремитесь оправдать свой ник), но что будет, если перед первым числом в строке пробел (а если числа разделяются несколькими пробелами)?

Вообще, смотрите на задачи глубже (ошибки ввода надо как-то обрабатывать) и тестируйте тщательней. Обязательно надо тестировать граничные условия.

--

Это мой последний комментарий здесь. Лимит-с....

Comment: буду фильтровать пробелы (удалять лишние) и тримить строку