# Как перевести текстовый файл чисел в  числовой массив?

Tags: c++

Всем привет)

Как можно перевести текстовый файл состоящий из вещественных чисел в числовой массив.
Например 
Есть файл *.txt

```
1 3.14 2 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
2 3 4 8 1
```

Надо их заносить в массив числовой.

Пытался через getline только он берет одну строку и потом через функцию atoi, но он считывает пробелы еще.

```
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
{
In.getline(array[i],100);
}
```

Есть пример, но значения в виде кучи записывает...

```
ifstream in("input.txt");
int i;
while (file) {
  file >> i;
}
```

Comment: `getline` - нормальная функция =)
А вот скажите - количество элементов в массиве фиксированное? Или оно от чего-то зависит? Просто можно схалявить. А еще можно использовать `operator >>` из `fstream`. А `atoi` в данном случае неудачный выбор. Начать с того, что она предназначена для того, чтобы преобразовывать строку в целые числа, а не в число в с плавающей запятой.

Comment: количество элементов думаю сначала фиксированное)

Comment: спасибо за ответ) через fstream заработало

Comment: @marioxxx, [вот здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/202681) обсуждался подобный вопрос для переменного числа аргументов.

Comment: Вопрос закрыт!)

Answer (score 8):

Вот так можно в вектор считать, буквально одной строчкой:

```
std::ifstream is(filename);
std::vector<double> a;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<double>(s), std::istream_iterator<double>(),
    std::back_inserter(a));
```

Answer (score 8):

Можно ещё так:

```
std::ifstream is(filename);
std::vector<double> a((istream_iterator<double>(is)),
                      istream_iterator<double>());
```

([проверка](http://ideone.com/dP6v2a), недавно обсуждалось [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/202681))

Comment: Ага, так проще.